# How to allow number or number/number in regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using asp.net c#.I am using validation expression.I want my text field will accept

number\number like 25\14  or it will accept only number like 23 So i want

13/ 13

or

11

I am using this express ^[0-9]{1,2}//[0-9]{1,2} but it is accepting number/number like 12/12 but also i want to allow number also like 10 only but only **two digits allow** like 23 not 130/340

I want **error** if user type number/ like 14/

```
I want text field will accept 13/34 two digits number
text will accept 14
text field not accept only bracket 
text field not accept 13/ or /23
```

Comment: Quite unclear to me. Can you give full list of accepted combinations?

Comment: i want text field will accept 13/34 two digits number

Comment: text field not accept 13/ or /23

Comment: text field not accept only bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this it will allow (00-99) and (00-99)(00-99)

`[0-9]{2}(/[0-9]{2}){0,1}`

So to the checklist

> I want text field will accept 13/34 two digits number **(YES -> accepted) [Link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D(%2F%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D)%7B0%2C1%7D%3F%24&i=12%2F12)**
>
> text will accept 14 **(YES -> accepted) [Link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D(%2F%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D)%7B0%2C1%7D%3F%24&i=12)**
>
> text field not accept only bracket **(YES -> not accepted)**
>
> text field not accept 13/ or /23 **(YES -> not accepted)**

Tested regex debugger
https://www.debuggex.com

Comment: I want only two digits

Comment: it does only 2 digits like this dd aswell as 2 digits separated by a slash like this dd\dd (do you want it to accept \dd and dd\ ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
^[1-9]\d(/[1-9]\d)?$
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b1-9%5d%5cd(%2f%5b1-9%5d%5cd)%3f%24&i=12)

Comment: I want if user  write 14 or 14/45 it will accept but only two number allow

Comment: system will not allow only bracket

Comment: BUT YOUR CODE IS ACCEPTION 12/

Comment: I dont want number/ and I want two digits numbers not 3 digits like 99/23

Comment: @WaqasAli What should `system will not allow only bracket` say to me?

Comment: @WaqasAli I changed my answer to match only two digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply `^[1-9][0-9](\/[1-9][0-9]){0,1}$`

Comment: i want number or number /number but number/ or /number